# What is the dot (".") notation in R?

Tags: r, tidyr

I want to group the tidyr dataset `relig_income` by religion, show the mean of the believers by `N_People` and order them `DESC` through the mean. I tried the first code but according to my online-course, the correct answer appears to be the second. What does the dot, in the function of arrange, means?

I am getting two different results.

1. My Code:

   tidy_df %>% group_by(religion) %>% summarise(mean_believers = mean(N_People)) %>% arrange(mean_believers, desc(mean_believers))
2. Correct Answer:

   tidy_df %>% group_by(religion) %>% summarise(mean_believers = mean(N_People)) %>% **arrange(.**, desc(mean_believers))

Comment: Cool, I understand now! Thank you for the reply and for the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.` is the notation for the data passed through `%>%`.
For example, you can reference specific columns of the data with `.$your_column`

Take a look at the [documentation](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html) for `pipe`

Comment: I see now. The dot is equal to the dataset (in this case tidy_df). I was using the arrange function wrongly.